# What's the best way to fetch an array

Tags: mysql, php, arrays

Alright, so I believe that there is a better way that I can fetch an array from the database, here's the code right now that I have.

```
$id = 1;
$userquery = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM login WHERE id='$id'");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($userquery, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    $username = $row['username'];
    $password = $row['password'];
    $email = $row['email'];
}
```

Comment: 1) use prepared statements/bind variables. 2) `id` is an integer, you have it in quotes 3) php question, so VTC time

Comment: Beside what Phil said, mysql` driver is deprecated. Use PDO or mysqli instead.

Comment: @Phil - When comparing to an `INT`, quotes around a number are ok.  The other way (`VARCHAR` against an unquoted number) gets in trouble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So If I am not wrong, you want a better way to get **all** the returned rows from mysql in a single statement, **instead of using the while loop**.

If thats the case, then I must say `mysql_` drivers do not provide any such functionality, which means that you have to manually loop through them using `foreach` or `while`.

**BUT**, since `mysql_` is already depricated, you are in luck! you can actually switch to a much better and newer `mysqli_` or the `PDO` drivers, both of which DO actually have functions to get all the returned rows.

For **mysqli_**: [`mysqli_result::fetch_all`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php)

For **PDO** : [`PDOStatement::fetchAll`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php)

Eg.

```
mysqli_fetch_all($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC); 
// The second argument defines what type of array should be produced 
// by the function. `MYSQLI_ASSOC`,`MYSQLI_NUM`,`MYSQLI_BOTH`.
```

Comment: AFAIK this doesn't make a difference performance-wise. it's handled exactly the same internally.

Answer (score 0):

Like the comments already told you: PHP's `mysql` driver is deprecated. And you should use prepared statements and parameters.

for example in `PDO` your code would look something like this:

```
//connection string:
$pdo= new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=my_db', 'my_user', 'my_password');

//don't emulate prepares, we want "real" ones:
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);

//use exception-mode if you want to use exception-handling:
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$id = 1;

//it's always better to strictly use backticks for db-names (db, tables, fields):
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `login` WHERE `id` = :id";

try
{
    //create your prepared statement:
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);

    //bind a parameter and explicitly use a parameter of the type integer (in this case):
    $stmt->bindParam(":id", $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);

    //execute the query
    $stmt->execute();
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
    exit("PDO Exception caught: " . $e->getMessage());
}


while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
    $username = $row['username'];
    $password = $row['password'];
    $email = $row['email'];
}
```

**here you go:** your `PHP`-`MySQL` routine is save against SQL-injections now and no longer uses deprecated `PHP`-functions! it's kinda state of the art ;)

Comment: While you are at it, if you will be using utf8, then include `charset=UTF8` in the `new PDO` call.